# I upgraded to iOS 9 and now I am not receiving any calendar invites

Tags: ios, calendar

I am not receiving any calendar invites after I did the iOS upgrade. In addition, when I add a calendar invite into my phone and add invitees, no one is receiving it

Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: In addition when I add a calendar invite into my phone and add invitees no one is receiving it

Comment: What service are you using? (Google? iCloud? Yahoo!?) Also, I think that your comment can be posted up in the question.